# Is it possible to run emulator from IC? and how?

Tags: electronics

I have an Emulator and Roms I would like to create a portable device to allow me to connect via RCA to a TV and play. Only I have no prior knowledge of how Integrated Circuits function or what they are capable of. If a IC would work, how does one go about programming one to load up the emulator? What other components aside from RCA and USB would I need? Any direction with this would be great and sorry in case I am not asking the proper questions.

I figured arduino is similar to what I am building in regards to circuitry/ electronics. Thanks in advance.

This is the only bit of information I have found online in 4 days thats not store bought.   [CLICK HERE](http://www.voja.rs/PROJECTS/GAME_HTM/2.%20Hardware.htm#Schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a chance, I am afraid.  The Arduino cannot do what you think it does.

Yes, you could *program* the Arduino to act like some of the simple old video games, but there is no way it can run a pre-existing emulator program like your computer can.

You need something more like a Raspberry Pi - in fact there is an interesting project that might be just what you want: [RetroPie](http://blog.petrockblock.com/retropie/)